# автоматический запуск приложения во время зарядки и перезагрузки на android

Tags: android

есть приложение слайд шоу и как сделать его загрузку во время зарядки?

Answer (score 6):

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Это в манифест

А это `PowerConnectionReceiver.java`

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                            status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;


        int chargePlugType = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        boolean usbCharge = chargePlugType == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
        boolean acCharge = chargePlugType == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
      //удалить лишние переменные, если они не нужны
    } 
}
```

Comment: Не знал, что такие интенты есть :)

Comment: @Barmaley, я тоже не знал, но гугл творит чудеса...